# Facebook like dialog hidden behind other page elements

Tags: css, facebook, z-index, visibility

I am having trouble getting the facebook pop out dialog to be on top of my nav bar and slideshow here:
http://d14599.u62.c14.ixinstant.com

I have search for several hours and all the solutions have not seemed to work.  Here is a list of what I have checked:
-overflow:hidden on other page elements causes problems.  I looked into this but my nav bar does not have this property.
-z- index only works for positioned elements.  I made sure my elements were positioned relative or absolute.
-I tried directly styling the js created facebook elements using things like

```
   .fb_iframe_widget{
   display:block !important;
   z-index:9999 !important;
  }
```

I'm not that good with CSS but have never been stuck this long on one single issue.

I am assuming the issue actually is with something I have done wrong elsewhere on the page, like the navbar itself, but I cannot see what it is.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really solve the issue, but what I have done is to hide the comment box. For this case it was acceptable. In the css file I added:

```
      .fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget {
       display:none;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched lot of things and tried it too but no solutions worked for me. I found one quick fix to solve [facebook like dialogbox overlap issue](http://www.webblogsforyou.com/facebook-like-box-overlapping-and-positioning-issue/) here and it worked for me.

Hope it could save others time, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to set the z-index for the element that holds the Facebook like button to be higher than the element the comment box was shown behind.